# Akka RoundRobinPool with OneForOneStrategy Restart

Tags: scala, akka

I have a simple "hello world" actor system with a `RoundRobinPool` router and a `OneForOneStrategy` restart strategy. I expect the following code to eventually (after a few failures) print 10 `"work done"` messages, but actually it seems that failed `Worker` actors aren't being restarted:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy._
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, OneForOneStrategy, Props}
import akka.routing.{RoundRobinPool, RouterConfig}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

/**
  * Worker Actor
  */
class Worker extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case DoIt => doit
  }

  def doit = {
    Thread.sleep(900)
    val dt = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond
    if ((dt % 2) == 0) throw new Exception("Error")
    else println("work done")
  }
}

/**
  * Message
  */
case object DoIt

/**
  * Entry point
  */
object PoolHelloWorld {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("PoolSystem")

    val supervisorStrategy =
      OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 20, withinTimeRange = 60 seconds) {
        case _: Exception => Restart
      }
    val routerConfig: RouterConfig =
      RoundRobinPool(2).withSupervisorStrategy(supervisorStrategy)
    val prop: Props = Props[Worker].withRouter(routerConfig)

    val worker = system.actorOf(prop, "Worker")
    (1 to 10).foreach { p =>
      worker ! DoIt
    }

    Thread.sleep(40000)
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you're doing wrong is including the `Thread.sleep(900)` in the actor; remove that call because it can cause weird behavior.

Also, your expectation of always seeing 10 `"work done"` print statements is mistaken, even with the restart strategy in place.

As you know, your actor's behavior is nondeterministic:

```scala
val dt = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond
if ((dt % 2) == 0) throw new Exception("Error")
else println("work done")
```

If `dt` happens to be an odd number for all 10 `DoIt` messages that you send to the actor, then obviously you'll see 10 `"work done"` statements. In the event that `dt` is an even number, then an exception is thrown and the routee *is* restarted. You can see this clearly if you override the `postRestart` hook on the actor:

```scala
class Worker extends Actor {
  ...
  override def postRestart(t: Throwable): Unit = {
    println(s"Restarted ${self.path} ...")
  }
}
```

If the routee is restarted, the `DoIt` message that it was processing is not re-processed, as the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/general/supervision.html#what-restarting-means) indicates:

> ...the restart is not visible outside of the actor itself with the notable exception that the message during which the failure occurred is not re-processed.

In summary, the only scenario in which you'll see 10 `"work done"` print statements is if the `dt` variable happens to be an odd number for all 10 `DoIt` messages. If, for any of those `DoIt` messages, `dt` is an even number, then the routee that was processing that message is restarted. Concomitant with the restart, that particular `DoIt` message is *not* re-processed, and you'll see fewer than 10 `"work done"` print statements (if any).

Comment: I add `Thread.sleep(900)` to the actor to emulate long running process, if this is wrong, what is the best practice how to do it (I mean emulate long running process). So, if the `DoIt` message is not re-sent it means that `receive` method is not invoked, does it means that invocation of Actor's processing logic, should always be defined in a Actor's method and then just called from `receive` and `postRestart` methods?